# Onchange datatable search input value filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field and trying to add the text field value to datatable search input field so that it can search/filter based on the value added, but even though the value is appearing in the search input field its not filtering until the key is pressed, below is the code which I used, please let me know if any other method to get the outcome.

sample table here for search:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

i have an text here, on click of this i need "test data" value to add in datatable search filed and filter it:

```
<p id="test">test data</p>


<script>
 $("#test").on("click", function(){
  var Clickvalue = $(this).text();
  $("input").val(Clickvalue);
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can fire the events by code. Share your code snippet.

Comment: Use `keyup` for this

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a testable example, I am not sure if I get the correct meaning.

Comment: i have used sharepoint webpart to embed the table and added data table for search feature, so now on click of some text in the page i need that text value to assign in datatable search input filed and filter it based on that value

Answer (score 0):

Judging on your title the search input is triggered by the onchange event. Changing the value in code does not trigger this event. However you can trigger the event yourself by code.

```js
$('#searchinput').on("change", function(){
  console.log('triggered')
});

$(".addSearch").on("click", function(){
  var Clickvalue = $(this).text();
  $("input").val(Clickvalue).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchinput">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="addSearch">Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td class="addSearch">System Architect</td>
            <td class="addSearch">Edinburgh</td>
            <td class="addSearch">61</td>
            <td class="addSearch">2011/04/25</td>
            <td class="addSearch">$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="addSearch">Garrett Winters</td>
            <td class="addSearch">Accountant</td>
            <td class="addSearch">Tokyo</td>
            <td class="addSearch">63</td>
            <td class="addSearch">2011/07/25</td>
            <td class="addSearch">$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Your test script would look like this.

```
$("#test").on("click", function(){
  var Clickvalue = $(this).text();
  $("input").val(Clickvalue).trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are not providing a reproducible example, I make a lot of guess. And even cannot test the result. This is not a good format for asking JS question.

But seems like you want the input box immediately filter the table. You probably want a `input` event instead of `change`, so you don't need to press enter/ unfocus the input box.

```
 $("#test").on("click", function(){
  var Clickvalue = $(this).text();
  $("input").val(Clickvalue);
  search(Clickvalue);
});

$("input").on( "input",function(){
    console.log(this.value);
  search(this.value);
})

var data_source = {1:"Tiger Nixon",2:"Garrett Winters"}

function search(input){
  var available_arr = [];
  for (var key in data_source){
    if (data_source[key].indexOf(input) > 0){
        available_arr.append(key);
    }
  }
  //function_you_use_for_construct_table(available_arr);
}

function function_you_use_for_construct_table(arr){
    //blah blah...
}
```